# Group By on column from joined table

Tags: mysql, index, join, group-by

its about the following query.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT phrase, infinitiv 
FROM `dict_verbs_all` `t` 
INNER JOIN `dict_verbs_all_language` `verbsGerman_c`
ON (`t`.`id`=`verbsGerman_c`.`verb_id`)
INNER JOIN `dict_verbs_german` `c` 
ON (`c`.`id`=`verbsGerman_c`.`verb_language_id`)
WHERE (t.phrase LIKE 'spie%' AND t.language=1) 
GROUP BY infinitiv 
LIMIT 5
```

It uses all the time filesort

```
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Here are my columns

```
CREATE TABLE `dict_verbs_all` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `phrase` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `language` smallint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uPhraseLanguage` (`phrase`,`language`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=337740 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `dict_verbs_all_language` (
  `id` int(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `verb_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verb_language_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `U_verb_conjugation` (`verb_id`,`verb_language_id`),
  KEY `verb_id` (`verb_id`),
  KEY `conjugation_id` (`verb_language_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `dict_verbs_german` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `infinitiv` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uInfinitiv` (`infinitiv`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have an index on all relevant columns but its not beeing used and I don't know why.
I hope you can help me how to eliminate using temporary and using filesort

Comment: Thanks for all of the information. Could you help us understand your question a bit better? Thanks.

Comment: The `LIMIT 5` means it will just return 5 rows max. Is it still slow?

Comment: the problem is that it uses Using temporary; Using filesort instead of the index

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the table "dict_verbs_german" is the last table joined.

When I last researched this, "using temporary; using filesort" meant MySQL was writing the the join result into a temporary table, then sorting. (See note below.) In order to avoid "using temporary; using filesort", you'd have to meet all these conditions.

- dict_verbs_german is the first non-constant table in the JOIN order, and
- dict_verbs_german has an index that marches the ORDER BY column list.

To avoid "using temporary", you'd have to meet all these conditions.

- dict_verbs_german is the first table in the JOIN order, and
- dict_verbs_german has an index that marches the ORDER BY column list.

**Note**: I'm talking about ORDER BY, because that's specifically what my research dealt with, and I'm pulling these notes from an email I wrote in 2010. I *think* the same optimizations applied to GROUP BY, but I could be wrong. Improvements to the optimizer over the last couple of years might have changed things, too.

---

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html)

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY . . ..
>   These cases include . . . joining many tables, and the columns in the
>   ORDER BY are not all from the first nonconstant table that is used to
>   retrieve rows. (This is the first table in the EXPLAIN output that
>   does not have a const join type.)

[MySQL documentation for optimizing limit queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html)

(I don't think this last reference will help you with *this* problem, but it's good to know where to find it.)

---

**Later . . .**

Cutting the WHERE clause seems to eliminate the filesort. (That might not be true for real-world data.) Maybe you can create a view without a WHERE clause and a LIMIT clause, then query the view and still avoid a filesort. I'm sorry that, for personal reasons, I'm not able to test that for you right now.